# Low pass filter vs lag compensator?

Tags: control, control-system

Is there any difference between a low pass filter and a lag compensator?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course.

- A first order low pass filter with the transfer function \$H(s)=\frac{A_o}{1+sT}\$, has one pole and no zero. Beyond the cut-off frequency and for rising frequencies the attenuation continuously increases.
- In contrast, a lag compensator with the transfer function \$H(s)=\frac{Ao(1+sT_2)}{1+sT_1}=A_o \frac{T_2}{T_1}\frac{s + \frac{1}{T_2}}{s + \frac{1}{T_1}}\$ where \$T_2<T_1\$, has one pole and one zero. Hence, beyond the cut-off frequency (pole magnitude) the attenuation also increases \$-\$ however, only until the zero will stop further attenuation and the damping will flatten out (and remains constant).

Comment: But as per your answer they both are some how  apparently similar that they allow low frequencies to pass and stop next higher frequencies

Comment: No - the lag compensator does NOT "stop" high frequencies. The attenuation of high frequencies remains constant ...and the damping factor can be selected (and remains fixed). By the way: Even a low pass cannot "stop" high frequencies.....it can only provide attenuation that increases with rising frequencies - but it cannot totally remove (stop) high frequency terms.

Comment: @engr the lag compensator is equivalent in behavior to a low pass filter at very high frequencies (\$\omega \rightarrow +\infty\$), but not in the frequency range \$[|p|,|z|]\$ in the lower frequency domain.